# Taking Symbol as input from script [sympy]

Tags: python, sympy

1.I'd like to define a function in a module that is interactive and can also take symbolic variables.

Let's say the function is

[image]
<sub>(source: [texify.com](http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C%21f%28x%29%5C%20%3D%5C%202x.gif))</sub>
.

Then I want it to work like

```
>>> function()
number: 3
6
>>> function()
number: x
2*x
>>> function()
number: a
2*a
```

The reason I want to prompt user input is that I'm thinking of functions with many arguments. I'm also thinking of using it in equations like `f(x)+g(y)=h(z)', so it will be useful if variables can be assigned instead of fixed.

---

2.Here's what I tried that didn't work. The reason is explained in kendall's answer.

I first made a module.

twice.py :

```
def twice():
    num = input('number: ')
    return 2*num
```

Then I ran it,

```
>>> import sympy as s
>>> x = s.var('x')
>>>
>>> import twice as t
>>> t.twice()
number: x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Do not use `input` in Python 2.x!! It's unsafe: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input It's the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())` so it can evaluate code. Use `raw_input()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you import it in a module, `twice()` runs in the module's global namespace and does not have access to the interactive session's global variables, such as `x`. That's the whole point of modules, after all.

This is typically rectified by passing variables to functions rather than having them operate on global variables.

Has nothing whatsoever to do with `sympy`, you'd have the same issue if you were using regular ol' Python numbers or whatever.

Comment: Does passing variables mean `def function(arg): `? Is there any way to keep it interactive somehow?

Comment: Yes, `def function(arg)`. To "keep it interactive," have your main script do the `input()` and pass the result to the function.

Comment: Could you provide the actual code? I don't know what to actually do with your advice...

Answer (score 1):

you should probably work in this way:

**what I recommend:**

this doesn't work exactly the way you want, but it keeps things simple and abstract. It doesn't matter if num is a simpy variable, an int, a float, a list... if it is a numeric object, twice will apply *2 to it. You may use twice in a lib safely.

twice.py

```
def twice(num):
    return 2*num
```

console

```
>>> import sympy as s
>>> x = s.var('x')
>>>
>>> import twice as t
>>> t.twice(x)
```

**for a version with user input:**

Here is a working solution. You shouldn't use it, because you are mixing io and functionality in your function. Which is bad.

twice.py

```
import sympy as s

def fetch_input():
    userInput = raw_input('number: ')
    try:
        return int(userInput)
    except ValueError:
        return s.var(userInput)

def twice():
    num = fetch_input()
    return 2*num
```

the raw_input is usually best when prompting for user input. It returns a string instead of trying to eval an expression.

Comment: Any idea how to keep it interactive?

Comment: what is not interactive with this version?

Comment: I was vague. I meant 'prompting user input'. I also added some comments at the end of section1, please take a look at it.

Comment: Is it possible to make it work for both numbers (evaluates) and variables (substitutes)?

Comment: I'm not keen on what weis26 is doing. But I think it would be better in the `fetch_input` function to use `return s.sympify(userInput)`. This should cover most possible inputs. And, for example, won't round a float to an int.